# Проблема с отрисовкой .png файла

Tags: c++, lua

Нужно отрисовать картинку, которая должна быть любой высоты и ширины, проблема в том, что если я отрисовываю ее по такому принципу -- Ширина экрана / 2, Высота экрана / 2, но картинка отрисовывается с погрешностью в 10-50 пикселей , потому что отрисовывается с 1го пикселя по X и Y (1го пикселя самой картинки)

Нужно написать функцию которая будет получать кол-во пикселей, нужное чтобы отрисовать картинку точно по центру, какой по ширине и высоте она бы не была.

Готовая отрисовка должна быть примерно такой
Ширина экрана / 2 + (Формула), Высота экрана / 2 + (Формула)

Вот как это должно выглядеть(примерно): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RSbo.jpg

Вот что получаю:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pySE.jpg

Comment: Вопрос неясен, попробуйте переформулировать или проиллюстрировать плиз

Comment: (Ширина экрана / 2) - (Ширина картинки / 2), (Высота экрана / 2) - (Высота картинки / 2). тег с++ не уместен

Comment: в том то и дело, что картинка может быть любой по размеру X и Y, тоесть, если я разделю например 500 на 2, получу 250, прибавив половину экрана + 250, картинка явно сильно "сьедет" с середины

Comment: не прибавить, а отнять нужно от середины экрана

Comment: если отнять, то она "сьедет" в противоположную сторону, логично же

Comment: acade всё правильно подсказал

Comment: Лично у меня, размеры картинки 420х420, когда пытаюсь сделать так, то у меня оно и близко не в середине экрана
Вот что выходит когда пытаюсь применить эту формулу:
X=473
Y=174
Разрешение при этом 1336х768, и картинка 420х420

Comment: Пример: 1920x1080. X= (1920 - 420) /2 = 750. Можно проверить, что середина картинки 750 + 210 = 960 лежит в центре экрана. Так что покажите свои попытки.

Comment: X=(1336/2) - (420/2)
Y=(768/2) - (420/2)
Это и близко не центр экрана
Центром по X является 668, но получается 458

Comment: X=473 Y=174 это координаты левого верхнего угла картинки относительно экрана

Comment: бред какой то получается, мне нужно просто отрисовать картинку по середине экрана, с учетом размеров этой картинки

Comment: Покажите, какая функция используется для рисования картинки.

Comment: Она тут не причем, сама формула не верная, я просто сделал print данной формулы

Comment: Думаю, на этом можно закончить дискуссию.

Comment: local screen = {[0] = 1336,[1] = 768}
local picture = {[0] = 420, [1] = 420}

for i = 0, 1 do
print(i.." = "..(screen[i] / 2) - (picture[i] / 2)) 
end
вывод идет такой
0 = 458.0
1 = 174.0
мне не очень верится что это центр экрана